# How do I put months in each array?

Tags: java

I'm making a program for expense statistics over a month; however, I don't know what I should do in the for loop in order to make it initialize each `MonthlyExpensePeriods` with the corresponding name of that month in the correct order?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){ 
    monthlyExpensePeriods[i] = new MonthlyExpensePeriods(month's name); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`DateFormatSymbols.getMonths()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getMonths--):

```java
String[] monthNames = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){ 
    monthlyExpensePeriods[i] = new MonthlyExpensePeriods(monthNames[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use `Month` enum objects rather than mere text of name of month.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){ 
    monthlyExpensePeriods[i] = new MonthlyExpensePeriod( Month.of( i ) ); 
}
```

## Use smart objects, not dumb strings

Using strings for special values, such as tracking each month of the year, is fragile and error-prone.

## `Month`

Instead, use objects.

In Java 8 and later, we have the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum class built-in. This enum predefines a dozen objects, one for each month of the year, each assigned to a named constant.

Your class `MonthlyExpensePeriod` should hold a member variable of type `Month`.

```
public class MonthlyExpensePeriod {
    // Member fields
    public Month month ;
    …

    // Constructor
    public MonthlyExpensePeriod( final Month monthArg ) {
        this.month = monthArg ;
        …
    }
}
```

To use that class and its constructor, pass one of the named constants.

```
new MonthlyExpensePeriod ( Month.MARCH )
```

You can retrieve one of the `Month` objects by month number. Notice the sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.

```
Month month = Month.of( 3 ) ;  // Month.MARCH
```

So your example code would look like the following. Change your `for` loop to count 1-12.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){ 
    monthlyExpensePeriods[i] = new MonthlyExpensePeriod( Month.of( i ) ); 
}
```

### Collections

You may want to use [Java Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) rather than mere arrays.

```
List< MonthlyExpensePeriod > periods = new ArrayList<>( 12 ) ;
for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){ 
    MonthlyExpensePeriod period = new MonthlyExpensePeriod( Month.of( i ) ) ;
    periods.add( period ); 
}
```

### Streams

I suppose we could get fancy and use streams. But in this case I do not see any added-value.

Calling [`Month.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#values()) returns an array of all the objects defined on the enum, in the order in which they were defined. From that, we can generate a stream by calling the utility class method [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html).

```
List < MonthlyExpensePeriod > periods =
        Arrays.stream( Month.values() )
                .map( month -> new MonthlyExpensePeriod( month ) )
                .collect( Collectors.toList() )
;
```

Or as a single-line of code.

```
List < MonthlyExpensePeriod > periods = Arrays.stream( Month.values() ).map( month -> new MonthlyExpensePeriod( month ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

You might want to make an unmodifiable copy of your list.

```
List < MonthlyExpensePeriod > periodsUnmod = List.copyOf( periods );
```

Or make the original list unmodifiable, by calling `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()`, as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61132631/642706).

```
List < MonthlyExpensePeriod > periods = 
        Arrays
        .stream( Month.values() )
        .map( month -> new MonthlyExpensePeriod( month ) )
        .collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableList() )
;
```

### Generating display text

You may want to display the name of the month.

Calling `Month::toString` generates text of the name in English in all caps. Instead you can automatically localize.

To localize, pass a [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) object to signal how long or abbreviated you want the name. Notice that `TextStyle` offers `STANDALONE` variations used in some languages (not English) where the month name appears outside the context of a date.

And pass a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms to use in localizing.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or Locale.US and so on.
String output = Month.MARCH.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , locale ) ;
```