# Can the list returned by a Java streams collector be made unmodifiable?

Tags: java, list, java-stream, collectors, unmodifiable

When working with Java streams, we can use a collector to produce a collection such as a stream.

For example, here we make a stream of the `Month` enum objects, and for each one generate a `String` holding the localized name of the month. We collect the results into a `List` of type `String` by calling  [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()).

```
List < String > monthNames = 
        Arrays
        .stream( Month.values() )
        .map( month -> month.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() )
;
```

> monthNames.toString(): [janvier, février, mars, avril, mai, juin, juillet, août, septembre, octobre, novembre, décembre]

To make that [list unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable), we can call [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) in Java 10 and later.

```
List < String > monthNamesUnmod = List.copyOf( monthNames );
```

➥ Is there a way for the stream with collector to produce an unmodifiable list without me needing to wrap a call to `List.copyOf`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an immutable list from an existing list using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013435/creating-an-immutable-list-from-an-existing-list-using-streams)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList`

Yes, there is a way: [`Collectors.toUnmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableList())

Like [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)), this feature is built into [Java 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10) and later. In contrast, `Collectors.toList` appeared with the debut of [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8).

In your example code, just change that last part [`toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) to `toUnmodifiableList`.

```
List < String > monthNames = 
        Arrays
        .stream( Month.values() )
        .map( month -> month.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) )
        .collect( Collectors.toUnModifiableList() )  //  Call `toUnModifiableList`.
;
```

### `Set` and `Map` too

The [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) utility class offers options for collecting into an unmodifiable `Set` or `Map` as well as `List`.

- [`Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableList())
- [`Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableSet())
- [`Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) (or [with `BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)))

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 we could use [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-).

```
List < String > monthNames =
    Arrays
        .stream( Month.values() )
        .map( month -> month.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) )
        .collect( 
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), 
            Collections::unmodifiableList) 
        )
;
```

Comment: FYI, calling [`Collections::unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) creates a view onto the original list rather than making a separate copy. But in the scenario given here, I suppose that has the same effect as a separate copy given that this code swallows the original list.